# ld returned 1 exit status c++ header linking

Tags: c++, header

I recenlty made a program where you can register/login into your account. I decided to split my code in smaller parts by using headers.  The error i get when running my program is undefined reference to `Log_In()'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status

So i have the following code:

```
    bool Log_In(){
    string username, password;
    string us, pw;
    system("CLS");
    cout<<"\n";
    cout<<"                                                         ~Facebook~                            \n";
    cout<<"\n";
    cout<<"                               Numele de utilizator: ";
    cout<<"                         ";
    cin>>username;
    cout<<"                               Parola: ";
    cout<<"                         ";
    cin>>password;

    ifstream in("A:\\CPP\\P Projects\\Login_register\\users_pass\\"+ username + ".txt");

    in>>us;
    in>>pw;

    if(us == username && pw == password)
        return true;
    else return false;
}
```

Log_In.cpp :

```
#include "../headers/Log_In.h"
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>

bool Log_In(){
    string username, password;
    string us, pw;
    system("CLS");
    cout<<"\n";
    cout<<"                                                         ~Facebook~                        \n";
    cout<<"\n";
    cout<<"                               Numele de utilizator: ";
    cout<<"                         ";
    cin>>username;
    cout<<"                               Parola: ";
    cout<<"                         ";
    cin>>password;

    ifstream in("A:\\CPP\\P Projects\\Login_register\\users_pass\\"+ username + ".txt");

    in>>us;
    in>>pw;

    if(us == username && pw == password)
        return true;
    else return false;
}
```

Log_In.h:

```
#ifndef LOG_IN_H
#define LOG_IN_H

#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

bool Log_In();


#endif
```

main.cpp:

```
#include "./headers/Log_In.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <windows.h>
.... 
bool log = Log_In();
```

full output: cd "a:\CPP\P Projects\Login_register" ; if ($?) { g++ main.cpp -o main } ; if ($?) { .\main }
main.cpp: In function 'int alegere(int)':
main.cpp:105:1: warning: control reaches end of non-void function [-Wreturn-type]
}
^
C:\Users\calex\AppData\Local\Temp\ccfcxK1Z.o:main.cpp:(.text+0x394): undefined reference to `Log_In()'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status

Comment: If you think the build command that compiles *and* links your program isn't relevant here, think again. The command that builds your program should be [included as part of your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/65967118/edit). Hint: if your build command does not contain any reference to `Log_In.cpp`, neither will your compiled code. Come link-time, any references to content therein will find no joy.

Comment: Also please copy.-paste (as text) the full and complete copy-paste of the error output into the question. Please [edit] your question to improve it. And please take some time to take the SO [tour], read [ask], as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Comment: ok, i just added the output

Comment: In the output you show, this is the command used to build your program: `g++ main.cpp -o main`. As you can see it only builds with the `main.cpp` file.  This seems to be the default for Visual Studio Code, you need to create your own build configuration file to be able to build a multi-source project. See e.g. [this Microsoft tutorial](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-mingw) on how to use and configure VSCode for C++ programming with MinGW, including examples of the configuration files needed to build and run your projects.

Comment: Hi! i managed to fix that but now i get this error: C:/Program Files/CodeBlocks/MinGW/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/8.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot open output file main.exe: Permission denied
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status

Comment: That latest error tend to happen when you try to build your program when it's already running. Please make sure its not running anywhere, not even in the background.